# Bond ETFs slowing down after 2015. - why?

Tags: investing, etf, bonds

I see a lot of bond ETFs have very low gain, or even stay flat during 2015. - today. 
For example [Eurozone Government Bond](https://etf.dws.com/en-lu/LU0290355717-eurozone-government-bond-ucits-etf-1c/) or [US Treasuries](https://etf.dws.com/en-lu/LU0429459356-us-treasuries-ucits-etf-1d/).

What is the reason for this?

Comment: @BobBaerker You should make that an answer.

Comment: @BobBaerker Please add that as an answer?